# SQL sort by group

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am looking for an intermediate between GROUP BY and ORDER BY.

I want to group rows by a Key. However, I cannot use an aggregate function like ARRAY_AGG to collect a group into a single row, for the simple reason that some of the bigger groups have millions of records in them, which causes severe memory issues, databases are not prepared for such big rows.

An alternative would be to sort the whole database by Key. However, I am using Presto through AWS Athena, and Presto needs to collect all the records in a single machine to sort them. The database is simply too big to fit into the memory of a single node, so this is not an option either.

I need something in between. Keep the rows with the same Key next to each other, without aggregating and without strictly sorting everything by Key. This way, the grouping can be done in a distributed manner, and there's no issue with enormous rows in the results.

Example:

Sample data

```
Key            | Data
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
London         | ["N J M London",null,null,"N J M","London",["United States"],null]
Moreno De Vega | ["V Moreno De Vega",null,null,"V","Moreno De Vega",null,null]
Paspatis       | ["G A Paspatis",null,null,"G A","Paspatis",null,null]
Macdonald      | ["A J Macdonald",null,null,"A J","Macdonald",null,null]
Masterman      | ["J Masterman",null,null,"J","Masterman",null,null]
Nørager        | ["C B Nørager",null,null,"C B","Nørager",null,null]
Maggiori       | ["L Maggiori",null,null,"L","Maggiori",null,null]
Nocito         | ["A Nocito",null,null,"A","Nocito",null,null]
Díaz Nieto     | ["R Díaz Nieto",null,null,"R","Díaz Nieto",null,null]
Christoforidis | ["D Christoforidis",null,null,"D","Christoforidis",null,null]
Sillen         | ["Ulla Sillen",null,null,"Ulla","Sillen",null,null]
Riew           | ["K Daniel Riew",null,null,"K Daniel","Riew",null,null]
Matsumine      | ["Hajime Matsumine",null,null,"Hajime","Matsumine",["United States"],null]
Taylor         | ["Fraser Taylor",null,null,"Fraser","Taylor",null,null]
Buser          | ["Aalen Gerd Buser",null,null,"Aalen Gerd","Buser",null,["Klinische Monatsblätter für Augenheilkunde, Artemis Zentren, Dillenburg,
```

Sample grouped by Key, **this is what I want**

```
Key            | Data
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
London         | ["N J M London",null,null,"N J M","London",["United States"],null]
London         | ["John London",null,null,"John","London",["Austria"],null]
Moreno De Vega | ["V Moreno De Vega",null,null,"V","Moreno De Vega",null,null]
Moreno De Vega | ["Victoria Moreno De Vega",null,null,"Victoria","Moreno De Vega",null,null]
Moreno De Vega | ["V. Moreno De Vega",null,null,"V.","Moreno De Vega",null,null]
Paspatis       | ["G A Paspatis",null,null,"G A","Paspatis",null,null]
Macdonald      | ["A J Macdonald",null,null,"A J","Macdonald",null,null]
Masterman      | ["J Masterman",null,null,"J","Masterman",null,null]
Masterman      | ["James Masterman",null,null,"James","Masterman",null,null]
```

EDIT:

My current attempts.

With GROUP BY and ARRAY_AGG. This is too heavy,

```
SELECT
  CAST(array_agg(_id) AS JSON) AS paper_id,
  CAST(array_agg(date) AS JSON) AS date,
  CAST(array_agg(title) AS JSON) AS title,
  CAST(array_agg(abstract) AS JSON) AS abstract,
  CAST(array_agg(keywords) AS JSON) AS keywords,
  CAST(array_agg(authors) AS JSON) AS authors,
  CAST(array_agg(author.name) AS JSON) AS name,
  CAST(array_agg(author._id) AS JSON) AS _id,
  CAST(array_agg(author.ids) AS JSON) AS ids,
  CAST(array_agg(author.firstnames) AS JSON) AS firstnames,
  CAST(array_agg(author.surname) AS JSON) AS surname,
  CAST(array_agg(author.countries) AS JSON) AS countries,
FROM main
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(authors) as t(author)
GROUP BY LOWER(author.surname)
```

With ORDER BY, again, too heavy:

```
SELECT
  _id,
  date,
  title,
  abstract,
  keywords,
  authors,
  author.name,
  author._id,
  author.ids,
  author.firstnames,
  author.surname,
  author.countries,
FROM main
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(authors) as t(author)
ORDER BY LOWER(author.surname)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh edited to include them

Comment: Something seems amiss with your problem.  Why are you returning so many millions of records?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is a big database. I need to list all the people in the database grouped by surname for a large-scale batch process. Some of the most common surnames (usually Chinese) have millions of people.

Comment: Have you considered going to a temporary Redshift or EMR cluster to tackle this job?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a great answer as to a work around to accomplish what you want. You correctly identified the limitation with sorting all records on a single machine in Presto. It's worth mentioning there is a close to complete effort by the Starburst team to implement distributed sort in Presto. Once this feature is merged and picked up by Athena, you'll be able try our the approach you mention.

If you want to try to apply the patch deploy Presto yourself sooner, here is the Pull Request:
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/9854

Disclaimer: I work for Starburst. But I'm answering this post as a Presto enthusiast.

Comment: Yeah, this is not very helpful in the short term. But thanks for the news anyways. I was wondering why sorting is centralized in Presto, implementing distributed merge sort for example should be relatively simple.

Comment: It's just something that hadn't been implemented yet.